# Does XMLUnit have an assert to ignore whitespace

Tags: java, junit, xmlunit

I want to compare two xml strings in a test, but the test keeps failing due to whitespace.

```
@Test
public void testForEquality() throws Exception {
 String myControlXML = "<msg><uuid>0x00435A8C</uuid></msg>";
 String myTestXML = "<msg><uuid>0x00435A8C</uuid>      </msg>";
 assertXMLEqual(myControlXML, myTestXML);
 Diff diff = new Diff(myControlXML, myTestXML);
 assertTrue(diff.similar());
}
```

Comment: Guess I should have looked for 5 more minutes     XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, XMLUnit can ignore whitespaces. See [API documentation](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/XMLUnit.html#setIgnoreWhitespace%28boolean%29) for details. You can enable it by setting:

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
```

Answer (score 14):

The API has changed with [XMLUnit 2.x](http://www.xmlunit.org/).

Now, for unit tests, you can ignore whitespace with a hamcrest matcher like so:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.xmlunit.matchers.CompareMatcher.isIdenticalTo;
...
assertThat(actual, isIdenticalTo(expected).ignoreWhitespace());
```

Or alternatively, with the builder API directly:

```java
import org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder;
...
boolean areDifferent = DiffBuilder.compare(left).withTest(right)
                                  .ignoreWhitespace().build().hasDifferences();
```